# gRPC Xamarin Client on local emulator refuses to connect to local server from computer

Tags: asp.net-core, xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2019, grpc

I am trying to make a gRPC Xamarin .Net Core client for android devices to connect to a local gRPC server. The server worsk with a local client on my computer but when I tried with an android client started on a local emulator I receive this error: "connection close by peer"

The server is started on local machine: https://localhost:5001
In the Xamarion prject, the address I am using is https://10.0.2.2:5001

Do you have any idea what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: local server on your PC? So use IP of your PC and not localhost

Comment: starting the server with my IP 192.168.1.5 I an not able to use my local PC client. I am receiving the error "The SSL connection could not be established" when I try to get the response from the server. Also from the Android Client from local emulator I still recevie "Connection closed by peer"

Comment: during delelopment [trust any certificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/troubleshoot?view=aspnetcore-3.1#call-a-grpc-service-with-an-untrustedinvalid-certificate) with ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback.